# How to filter data based on two colums and replace in R?

Tags: r, filter, replace

In my .csv dataset, there are data like:

```
no     name     city    id
1301    Lee       A    1301-1     
1001    Lee       A    1001-2
1201    Lee       A    1201-4
1402    Sam       B    1402-4    
1622    Sam       C    1622-5
```

what I want to get is if rows both have the same name and city, then change the string in the id column to same with which in the smallest "no". The result should be:

```
no     name     city    id
1301    Lee       A    1001-2     
1001    Lee       A    1001-2
1201    Lee       A    1001-2
1402    Sam       B    1402-4    
1622    Sam       C    1622-5
```

How to get it in R?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(name, city) %>%
  mutate(id =id[which.min(no)])
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   name, city [3]
     no name  city  id    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1  1301 Lee   A     1001-2
2  1001 Lee   A     1001-2
3  1201 Lee   A     1001-2
4  1402 Sam   B     1402-4
5  1622 Sam   C     1622-5
```

Answer (score 0):

We could `arrange` the data and then get the `first` element of 'id' grouped by 'name', 'city'

```
library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
    arrange(name, city, no) %>%
    group_by(name, city) %>% 
    mutate(id = first(id)) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     no name  city  id    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1  1001 Lee   A     1001-2
2  1201 Lee   A     1001-2
3  1301 Lee   A     1001-2
4  1402 Sam   B     1402-4
5  1622 Sam   C     1622-5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(no = c(1301L, 1001L, 1201L, 1402L, 1622L), name = c("Lee", 
"Lee", "Lee", "Sam", "Sam"), city = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C"
), id = c("1301-1", "1001-2", "1201-4", "1402-4", "1622-5")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```